# How I place 3 links in the same line on HTML without using CSS

Tags: html

I need to put 3 links in the same line aligned like left, center, and right without using CSS.

---

Its something like this, I hope this helps

[image: the text are 3 links]

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do all of this without using any CSS, you can use tables.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First link</td>
    <td>Second link</td>
    <td>Third link</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise you don't really have much of an option if you want the spacing and all you got on your image example. I would also not recommend using tables all that much, because pretty much everything should be responsive for mobile devices these days, and tables are really hard to fit in to a 320px of screen width.

Comment: The question says "aligned like left , center and right"

Comment: @Quentin So all you did was added your own answer in by just adding 100% of width to the table, which is kind of unclear if the op even wants it to be full width. Dear lord.

Comment: If the link is to be aligned to the right then it has to be full width to reach to the right. You seem to have skipped over the other attributes that were added.

Comment: @Quentin Point being, you could've just edited my answer as it was almost on point instead of just downvoting it and doing your own. But you're right, I totally missed the alignments.

Comment: I'd already written my answer before yours appeared. You hadn't marked your answer as community wiki, so it would have been wrong to make substantial edits to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely bad practice. A list of links is not tabular data. HTML is not a layout tool. This is how things were done in 1996. The web is better (in some ways) now and we do not do things this way now.

---

It is possible to hack a layout with a table and obsolete presentational attributes. The data is not tabular, however, so this is bad food for screen readers and search engines.

It is also not HTML 5. What you want to achieve is not possible with HTML 5. This is HTML 4.01 Transitional which, when it was released two decades ago, was only ever intended as a stop-gap while people converted over to using CSS for presentation.

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="33%"><a href="/">A link</a></td>
    <td width="34%" align=center><a href="/">A link</a></td>
    <td width="33%" align=right><a href="/">A link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming you can add inline styling ,you can use this

```
<div>
<a href="" >firstlink</a>
<a href="" style ="text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;">secondlink</a>
<a href="" >thirdlink</a>
</div>
```

else you can use one by answered by community wiki